# Server-Sent Events with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, server-sent-events

I have a web app which sends some data from a js script to a php server which inserts it into a mysql database. I also need to notify all other clients that the data has been sent and send it to them.

I'm trying to use Server-Sent Events to do this but I'm having some trouble grasping the concept. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var source = new EventSource("../Server/insertMessage.php");
    if(typeof(EventSource) == "undefined") {
        alert("event source doesnt work");
    } else { alert("event source works"); }

    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        alert(event.data);
        // do stuff with event.data
    };
});
```

Elsewhere in my js script, I send an AJAX request to insertMessage.php with POST parameters as the data details. Does this trigger the server-side event? Here's my server side code:

**insertMessage.php**

```
if(isset(// check POST to see if the right request was sent)) {
    // insert data into database
    // ...
    // ...

    // Send the new data to listeners
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    // Create data array
    $dataArray = array("data" => $data, "moreData" => $moreData);
    // Encode JSON
    $callback = json_encode($dataArray);
    // Send it
    echo "data: $callback";
    flush();
}
```

While the "event source works" alert is sent, I never get the `event.data` alert, even though I am making the AJAX call to `insertMessage.php`. I may not completely understand Server-Sent Events yet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to read about Node.js and web sockets. PHP can't initiate any connections. The client has to connect to the server.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois but I'm not initiating any connections using PHP. I'm just trying to send some data from the server to the client when an event happens. I'm not completely sure if I'm triggering the event from the server correctly.

Comment: You need to use for that Node.js and web sockets. PHP can't do what you want.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois would you mind giving me more details as to how I would do that?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois is absolutely correct on this. What you're trying to do is to `push` data **from** the server to a client. This can't be done if there is no active connection between the client and the server. The technology you should be looking for is preferably `push notifications` or `websockets`. You can use `AJAX` as well, but it's tricky and you need to send requests to the server every N seconds to "check" for new data.

Comment: It is inaccurate to say that PHP does not support websockets. It's a standard that
PHP support, like any other server side language. One application is [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use server sent events on this way:

Use this:

```
session_write_close(); // Close the session before your response! It helps your client create new requests to you server during the execution.

$echo= "id: $time" . PHP_EOL; // Important!
$echo.= "retry: ".$retry_time."" . PHP_EOL;  // Handle reconnect time (ms)
$echo.= "event: message" . PHP_EOL; // Event message type
$echo.= "data: {\n"; // JSON
$echo.= "data: \"data\": \"$data\" \n";  // JSON
$echo.= "data: }\n"; // JSON
$echo.= PHP_EOL; // Important!
```

Line breaks are really important in Eventsource!

You are able to use PHP for SSE but always keep in mind you should close the SESSION a soon as possible during the execution!

My stress test results: (Server config: 4Core@2.3Ghz,8Gb Ram,100/100Mbit) Ubuntu 14.04+Apache, Max connection: 1024

With 100 Connection Load = 0.14, with 1 SQL query/tick and 1sec refresh rate.

Below 500-600 active user you are able to use PHP for SSE without any problem, even with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because when your JavaScript is creating the EventSource or is doing an HTTP GET. So your PHP code is not returning anything. You can't do POST requests with an EventSource.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line `echo "\n\n";`

Your code will look like this:

```
if(isset(// check POST to see if the right request was sent)) {
    // insert data into database
    // ...
    // ...

    // Send the new data to listeners
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    // Create data array
    $dataArray = array("data" => $data, "moreData" => $moreData);
    // Encode JSON
    $callback = json_encode($dataArray);
    // Send it
    echo "data: $callback";
    echo "\n\n";
    flush();
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it